# What is the difference between "closing the shop" and "closing up the shop"?

Tags: prepositions, phrase-meaning, sentence-meaning, difference, phrasal-verbs

I read a story and found a sentence : they were closing up the shop.
As a learner of English if I have to write , I would simply write: they were closing the shop.
I would like to know what is the difference between the two: "closing the shop" and "closing up the shop".

Comment: The same difference between someone saying: "Eat your vegetables" and "Eat up your vegetables" the latter suggests the plate should be left clean.

Comment: Could you write the sentences that came before and after, please? Sometimes, the context, can make a big difference.

Comment: [correction: I would like to know what X is///not what is x]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Verb + "*up*" (eg "washing up", "eating up", "drying up" etc) *tends* to refer to the *process* of doing something to completion.

So, "closing the shop" could be taken to mean simply locking it up so that customers can no longer enter, whereas "*closing up* the shop" could involve the entire process of closing for business at the end of the day, including locking the door, counting the money, doing a stock-check, turning on the alarm etc. Incidentally, in British English, counting the money in a cash register is often called "cashing up".

This also assumes that your context makes it clear "closing the shop" doesn't mean *permanently*, and it is just for the day, ie at the close of business.